# Eclipse JSP editing with WTP doesn't find variable and class definitions

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I'm using Eclipse (3.6.1 on OS X) to write Java and JSP. Unfortunately, our JSPs contain a lot of Java -- I'd prefer to keep as much Java as possible in .java files, but that won't change, at least for a while.

I recently installed the Web Tools Project (WTP) version 1.1 and 1.2 to get better functionality when editing JSP. However, it doesn't do many things I'd expect. E.g., I cannot select a class name in the JSP and hit F3 (unsure of the function name) to open the class definition. In addition, in many cases Eclipse/WTP isn't aware of variables and/or class definitions that are present in JSP files that include the file containing the variable or class reference. That is, it reports 
" cannot be resolved to a variable", etc. I searched the Eclipse documentation -- especially http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.doc.user/topics/overview.html --  for guidance on how to configure WTP to present this info, to no avail.

Thanks
Arthur

Comment: What kind of project is it?  Are you able to develop Servlets in that project without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way for Eclipse to be sure which main JSP file, if any, the fragment file you're editing is included in, and should be used for this purpose.